How to update cached data in the background with RxJS
I'm building an Angular app that requires some data from an API. On the first call I'm caching the data to local storage. I want to make sure the data is always up to date, so my idea was to implement it like this:

On subsequent calls, if data is cached, display the cached data first
Then make an API call in the background
Compare hashes
If hashes don't match, show notification that the data is not up to date

Sounds good but I couldn't find a way to implement it. Here's bits of code for context:
  // init method, fetching data, setting things up

  private initGame(): void {
    this.layout.showLoader();

    this.countries
      .getCountries$()
      .pipe(
        takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef),
        take(1),
        finalize(() => {
          this.layout.hideLoader();
        }),
        map((rawCountries) => this.countriesFilter.transform(rawCountries)),
      )
      .subscribe((countries) => {
        this.playService.setCountries(countries);
        this.playService.nextQuestion();
      });
  }

// getting data from the API

 public getCountries$(getCached = true): Observable<IRawCountryData[]> {
    if (getCached) {
      const cachedCountries = this.cache.getCache<IRawCountryData[]>(
        this.localStorageKeys.countries,
      );

      if (cachedCountries !== null) {
        return of(cachedCountries);
      }
    }

    return this.api.get$<IRawCountryData[]>(this.host).pipe(
      tap((countries) => {
        this.cacheCountries(countries);
      }),
    );
  }

// method to run in the background, after rendering the cached data

  private updateCachedCountries(): void {
    this.countries.getCountries$(false).subscribe((countries) => {
      const isCacheUpToDate = this.countries.isCacheUpToDate(countries);

      if (isCacheUpToDate) return;

      this.countries.cacheCountries(countries);

      // ...
    });
  }

My idea was to run updateCachedCountries in the finalize block but then of course it is run synchronously, blocking the UI which defeats the whole purpose. I can't say I'm too comfortable with RxJS, so my question is, is there a RxJS operator or a trick I can use to achieve the desired behaviour? Or perhaps there's a better way altogether? Thanks!

why cache to local storage?  Wouldn't this already be in memory?  (local storage is best used for trivial things like view options)


Phil Karlton - There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.

You will have to check the server data to compare against your cache to see if it's changed, whether or not if it's done "in the background" (not sure what you mean by this) or not. If you are checking on every request - it defeats the purpose of having a cache as (unless the request is computationally intensive, i.e it's taking ages to complete), then you might as well just get the data fresh each time.
If you still really want/need caching, I suggest you cache at an interval to keep this simple.
const CACHE_INTERVAL = 120000;
interval(CACHE_INTERVAL).pipe(
   tap(() => makeRequestAndCache())
);

Then simply check against your cache (as you did) when making the request.
